Date criteria not working in Spring boot criteria builder
I am applying a date criteria in my Java Springboot project through criteria builder but it's not working. All the records are being fetched and the conditioning on date is getting ignored.
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<FilesInfoModel> query = builder.createQuery(FilesInfoModel.class);
        Root<FilesInfoModel> root = query.from(FilesInfoModel.class);

        Timestamp sqlTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(restrictProfileDateTime);

        query.where(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdDate"), sqlTimestamp));
        query.where(builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdDate"), Timestamp.valueOf(restrictProfileDateTime.plusDays(1))));
        query.where(builder.equal(root.get("fileType"), deltaScreeningFileType));
        query.select(root);
        List<FilesInfoModel> filesInfoList = session.createQuery(query).getResultList();

I tried putting greaterThanOrEqualTo & lessThanOrEqualTo to the date and date+1 values. The variable on which I am applying the condition is datetime2 data type in SQL Server DB table. So it should fetch only records with that date but instead it's giving all the records and the condition is getting ignored.

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work and stay away from the java.sql.Timestamp class, which was a hack on the already poorly designed Date class used up until 10 years ago when java.time came out. Depending on the type in your database you may need an OffsetDateTime or LocalDateTime.

Thank you! This helps. I will keep this in mind in future developments and study how date time class works.

Oracle Tutorial: Date Time Hibernate supports java.time at least since Hibernate 5.

Calling CriteriaQuery.where() multiple times does not add the predicates. The javadoc states: Replaces the previously added restriction(s), if any.
So the code should be changed something like this (untested):
    query.where(builder.and(
        builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdDate"), sqlTimestamp),
        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get("createdDate"), Timestamp.valueOf(restrictProfileDateTime.plusDays(1))),
        builder.equal(root.get("fileType"), deltaScreeningFileType)
    );


Yes, this works! I wasn't aware that the predicates don't get stacked but instead, they get replaced. Thank you!
